# Prototype.then isn't being used

Tags: javascript, promise, bluebird

I've been stumped with promises for awhile: I'm using [bluebird](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bluebird) Promise within a post request for an asynchronous function, and then using `.then()` to show the results of it and putting it into a `res.json()`. Problem is, I don't see `.then()` being used at all.

```
var transcribe = function(){
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
        speech.startRecognition(aux.gsUri, aux.fileType, function(err, operation, res) {
            if (err) {
                console.error(err);
            }
            else {
                operation.on('error', function(err){
                    console.error(err);
                }).on('complete', function(transcript){
                    var returnAllTranscripts = [];
                    transcript.forEach(function(block){
                        returnAllTranscripts.push(block.transcript);
                    });
                    return returnAllTranscripts;
                });
            }
        });
    })
}
transcribe().then(function(data){      //transcribe() function works
    console.log("Now on THEN");        //but not .then(), logging here
    res.json(data)
});;
```

Comment: You need to read about the fundamentals of how promises work.  You aren't resolving/rejecting the Promise anywhere so you won't get to .then/.catch of your promise chains.

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: @VtoCorleone ah, I was under the assumption I can disregard those two parameters and return whatever I got from speech.starRecognition. Thanks.

Comment: @Mati then() isn't invoked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to resolve/reject your Promise to hit the then/catch of your promise chain.

```
var transcribe = function(){
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
    speech.startRecognition(aux.gsUri, aux.fileType, function(err, operation, res) {
      if (err) {
        console.error(err);
        return reject(err); // <-- REJECT ERROR HERE
      } else {
        operation.on('error', function(err){
          console.error(err);
          return reject(err); // <-- REJECT ERROR HERE
        }).on('complete', function(transcript){
          var returnAllTranscripts = [];
          transcript.forEach(function(block){
            returnAllTranscripts.push(block.transcript);
          });
          return resolve(returnAllTranscripts); <-- RESOLVE "THEN" VALUE HERE
        });
      }
    });
  })
}

transcribe().then(function(data){      //transcribe() function works
  console.log("Now on THEN");        //but not .then(), logging here
  res.json(data)
})
.catch(err => console.log(err));
```

Comment: Worked like a charm, thank you! It actually worked even without using "return"

Comment: Yea.  The 'return' statement is not needed but I use it to implicitly say that the method is done at that point.